# How to put a glyphicon with tooltip inside a form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm working with bootstrap. I want to put a glyphicon inside the form text with a tooltip. I can put the glyphicon in the right side of the form text but the tooltip doesn't work.

any ideas?

this is the html

```
<div class="right-inner-addon table-error">
  <a>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign red" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Campo obrigatório."></i>
    <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.right-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.right-inner-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;    
}
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: can you add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Tooltips are not going to show up by themselves, you have to initialize them. See answer below

Comment: Yes, I know that. Maybe I didn't explain correctly.
I want something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pfrutuoso/n9eu89et/4/

Comment: See my updated answer, you have a CSS property that prevents the tooltip from showing up... fiddle example included shows it working :)

Comment: don't forget to mark the question as answered if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Re-read your question, so here's an update.

Tooltips are not going to show up by themselves, you have to initialize them.  Here's the blurb in their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples)

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.

To initialize them, follow the JS snippet below.

Also, your code has the CSS property:

```
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    /* pointer-events: none;  <!-- remove this line */
}
```

You need to remove it since that prevents the trigger to the tooltip.  You also need to specify the `data-placement` property (right, left, etc) since it is missing.

See running [example here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/n9eu89et/3/)

---

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        'html': true
    })
});
```